# stop 2 sliders in a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a serious problem , i would like to know how to resolve a problem in javascript or jquery , so i have sliders  input type="range" , both of them have 100 as a max value , like that:

```html
 <input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="one">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="two">
```

so in order to stop both of them in a certain position ,i mean , when the both sliders are in the value 100 , for example : the fist one is in 30 position , and the second is 70 , the sliders couldn't go more , or each of them in 50 .

to do the manipulation in javascipt , i took the value of the first slider and the value of the second onet, and i put them in one variable co2 
var co2 = slider1 + slider2

then i wrote ,

```js
var co2 = slider1+slider2
                  
                  if(co2>=100){
                      
                       document.getElementById("one").disabled()=true;
                       document.getElementById("two").disabled()=true;
                      
                    }
```

it works it stops the 2 sliders at all , for me i would like only to not leave them going more the value 100 , not to stop them

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you want.

```js
var elOne = document.getElementById("one"),
  elTwo = document.getElementById("two"),
  res = document.getElementById("result");

var result = 0;

elOne.addEventListener("input", function() {
  showResult("one");
}, false);

elTwo.addEventListener("input", function() {
  showResult("two");
}, false);

function showResult(slider) {
  result = parseInt(elOne.value) + parseInt(elTwo.value);
  if (result >= 100) {
    if (slider === "one")
      elOne.value = 100 - parseInt(elTwo.value);
    else
      elTwo.value = 100 - parseInt(elOne.value);

  }
  res.innerHTML = parseInt(elOne.value) + parseInt(elTwo.value);
}
```

```css
#result {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1em">
  <h2>Total</h2>
  0 <input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="one">100 0
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="two">100
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thank you very much @Jeshwel for your answer , but i want that the 2 sliders don't continue to move if the p.value+q.value = 100 as you wrote, but i can go back if i want with the 2 sliders

Comment: I am not getting you, can you make you reqs: more clear? you want both sliders to stop moving when total reaches 100; and they should not go back also? In my code it stops slider from moving ahead when it reaches 100 but value of slider 1 or 2 can be decreased and both can be re-adjusted again if needed.

Comment: i m going to explain with 2 examples , sorry if i didn't be clear , so i have to sliders ,1 and 2 , the first one has a max value 100 , and the second one 100. each slider depends on the other ,accroding to us the value of both sliders is 200 , but the value that the 2 sliders needs to reach is 100 , they have to stop moving in that point , otherwise if i want to come back to the 0 point i can do it .for examples :if the slider one is in the middle , it means that the slider2 has not to surpass the middle.an other example if th move all the slider1 , the second one that s not have to move